# Fraction Word Problem: Please help me Understand it.

Tags: fractions, word-problem

Multiple Choice:
How many otters are there in a group of 27 penguins and otters if there are four fifths as many penguins as otters?

My reasoning is $\frac{1}{5} \cdot \frac{27}{1}$ are otters.
So there are 5.4 otters out of 27. ~6 or (A) 6.

Choices:
(A) 6
(B) 15
(C) 21
(D) 22

The answer is stated as: (B) 15

Comment: Do you really think there are $5.4$ otters?  If $x$ is the number of otters, then the number of penguins is $\frac 45\times x$ so...

Comment: Use simultaneous equations, so let x be the number of penguins and y be the number of otters then $x + y = 27$, find the other equation and solve for x and y.

Comment: "There are four fifths as many penguins as otters" doesn't mean $\frac{4}{5}$ of the group is penguins and $\frac{1}{5}$ is otters! It means that whatever number of otters you have, the number of penguins is $\frac{4}{5}$ of that amount.

Comment: Like others have said in the comments, you want to set up a system of equations. Let $x$ represent the number of penguins, and $y$ represent the number of otters. If you know there are $27$ penguins and otters altogether, one equation is $x+y = 27$. Now, the next equation you'll need is the one that comes from "there are four fifths as many penguins as otters." That means the number of penguins is four-fifths the number of otters. Try to come up with the second equation and see if you can solve it, if you can, post your own answer!

Comment: Thanks all i will. I am a little slow at logical reasoning but i will get better!

Comment: $y\frac{4}{5} + y = 27$ which is then $y\frac{4}{5} \cdot \frac{5}{4} + y = \frac{27}{1} \cdot\frac{5}{4}$ --> y + y = 33.75 --> 2y/2 = 33.75/2 --> y = 16.875. Apologies if this format is messy.

Comment: Before trying to get rid of the fractions by multiplying by $\frac{5}{4}$, combine the two terms on the left hand side. You have $\frac{4}{5}y+y = 27 \Rightarrow \frac{4}{5}y+\frac{5}{5}y = 27$, what comes next?

Comment: OHH Thanks a bunch. $y\frac{4}{5} + y{5}{5} = 27$ \Rightarrow $y\frac{9}{5} \cdot \frac{5}{9} = \frac{27}{1} \cdot {5}{9}$ \Righarrow $y = \frac{135}{9}$ \Rightarrow $y = 15$. I haven't used MathJax or LaTex before today, but due to taking the chance in asking for help, I've created a new document to better help me consolidate what has been taught to me. Thank you!!

Comment: Nice job! You should post your solution as the answer so that if somebody else finds this page, they can see how you resolved it.

Comment: And, here's a good page to keep pinned for help with [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: Yea since I was daunted by all the symbols used in the notation, that was my first go to, in hopes of not making a fool out of myself. :p

Answer (score 1):

Starting first, as pointed out by @Ajay and @Amaan M, this equation uses a Simultaneous Equation that can be used to solve for a single variable.

$x$ = penguins, $y$ = otters.

This equation is used because both the $x$ and $y$ variables add up to $27$.

Simultaneous Equation: $x + y = 27$

Because x is equal to $\frac{4}{5}$ of y, which is "Four Fifths as many Penguins as otters", we can say $x = \frac{4}{5}y$

Substitution: $y + \frac{4}{5}y = 27$

Evaluation:
$\frac{4}{5}y + \frac{5}{5}y = 27 \Rightarrow \frac{9}{5}y \cdot \frac{5}{9} = \frac{27}{1} \cdot {5}{9} \Rightarrow y = \frac{135}{9} \Rightarrow y = 15$

Comment: Thanks @Nightflight, It seems I'm gonna have to change a few variables around in my notes :D